# absolute File path to relative file path

Tags: filepath, filereader, relative-path

I have a class library project (D:/projectName/SampleClassPrj) and a console application project D:/projectName/ConsolePrj.
In class library project, a json file test.json and a class sample.cs (read and deserialise json) both present.
d:/projectName/SampleClassPrj/test.json
d:/projectName/SampleClassPrj/sample.cs

This works with absolute path like,
d:/projectName/SampleClassPrj/test.json

but not working with relative path.

with relative path, by using file not found error as it is trying to find the file in the console (running) application assembly folder.
D:/projectName/ConsolePrj/bin/test.json
please help to find the solution

Comment: I changed the build action of json file as embedded resource, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

- first, check json file property "copy if newer".
  [image]
- then, use Appdomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ConnectionString.txt"));
```

Comment: I am still getting an error as Could not find file 'D:\Test\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\sample.json'

Comment: @user15096128 Can you get more info? you cloud post github link or gist.

Comment: @user15096128 your json file in library project or console?

Comment: in Library project Still getting an error at
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "sample.json"))

Could not find file 'D:\Test\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\sample.json'
Here json file is present in another class library project with path
D:\Test\ClassLibProject\sample.json

Comment: @user15096128  you can not add files to library project. you should put on the console.

Comment: Yes I have moved the file to console app project still error as Could not find file 'D:\Test\ConsoleApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\sample.json' where as actual path of the file is  'D:\Test\ConsoleApp\sample.json'

Comment: @user15096128 Have you set file property "copy if newer"? I had run above code successfully.

Answer (score 0):

var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.Substring(0, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location.IndexOf("bin\")));
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path, "sample.json"))

for .NET core 3.1
This worked for me